# Constructor for this disjoint-set data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, linked-list

We need to implement a class called DisjointSet.java that will be our data-structure for the program we are using. Here are the instructions for creating the data structure:

[image: instructions]

I understand most of the instructions and how to code it, but I am a little confused what a "list of Node objects" will look like in the constructor method? I made a inner Node class, and created a Node parent in the DisjointSet.java class, but I don't really know what he wants for the "list of Node objects".

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

> I am a little confused what a "list of Node objects" will look like in the constructor method?

List of node objects does not need to be initialized in the constructor. It is an initially empty list of `Node` objects, so you would initialize it like this:

```
List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would replace the list `List<Node>` with a `Map<T,Node>`, so that it is faster to find (i.e. O(1) instead of O(n) lookup time).

Comment: We have not learned about Maps yet so I will go with the first proposition. Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: I think he is confused about the semantics. Is that a list of all nodes in the set? I think so.